# Retrieve pandas dataframe column index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Say I have a pandas dataframe. I can access the columns either by their name or by their index.

Is there a simple way in which I can retrieve the column index given its name?

Comment: Your question is unclear as we have 3 answers here, are you asking how to get just the columns: `list(df)` or `df.columns` or asking how to get the column array index position by name?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, the second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) on the `columns` `Index` object to return the ordinal index value:

```
In [283]:
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list('abcd'))
df

Out[283]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b, c, d]
Index: []

In [288]:
df.columns.get_loc('b')

Out[288]:
1
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by index exactly?

I bet you are referring to index as a list index, right?

Because Pandas has another kind of index too.

From my first understandying, you can do the following:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
my_columns = my_df.columns.tolist()
print my_columns # yields ['A', 'B', 'C'], therefore you can recover the index by just doing the following
my_columns.index('C') #yields 2
```

Comment: This returned `AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'index'`

Comment: sorry, check it again. I converted it to a list now. i am on my mobile, so i may commit some mistakes =P